# Running a block with a timeout in Scala without using Futures?

Tags: scala

Is there a way to running a function with a timeout in Scala, **without Futures**?

For example, something like:

`val result = runWithTimeout (timeout, function}`

The reason to avoid `Future`, is because we work in a complex running environment and I would like to avoid spanning the threads and managing ExecutionContext.

Comment: Frist not even futures support timeout, second how do you expect to make a timeout without another thread to trigger the time timeout?

Comment: What it should return if timeout will be exceeded?

Comment: @BorisAzanov Exception? None?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez what do you mean? With Futures you could do something like:

```
  def runWithTimeout[T](timeout: Duration)(f: => T)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Option[T] = {
    try {
      Some(Await.result(Future(f), timeout))
    } catch {
      case e: TimeoutException => None
    }
  }
``` (sorry for the formatting)

Comment: @Johnny that actually doesn't stop the computation, it just keeps running until finishing. But the thread that was blocked with the await would be awakened with the timeout exception.

Comment: Yes, so I'm ok with a blocking solution. And I know that maybe I'm missing some understanding here :)

Comment: @Johnny what does that mean? That is exactly what the the Future-Await solution does.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I understand that. But it's doing it with `Future`, something that I'm trying to avoid, somehow.

Comment: @Johnny but why do you want to avoid a **Future**? Again, doing something until a timeout requires a new thread or something concurrent. And, since you can not really cancel a thread, you can only let it finish the work without caring. A better solution to all this problem would be to use some effect system like **cats-effect**, **fs2**, **monix** or **Zio**, which have lightweight fibers and timers and support cancellation, but if you do not want to add futures, I may assume that you would be even more against of adding a whole effect system.

Comment: Ok @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, thanks. So it's somewhat an open question. How would you suggest me to do something like that? In the end, I just want to stop function execution if it hasn't ended in a specific time period.

Comment: In general not possible on JVM. You cannot stop ongoing thread. At best you can send `interrupt` signal to it, but the thread can totally ignore it. If you have IO monads you can cancel ongoing computation but what it does to to fail execution between finishing running one layer and starting another. In-between it is impossible as you cannot stop thread from running.

Comment: The only way of making this possible id by making this function checking on its own if it is running more time than allowed and exiting on its own - if this is some arbitrary function that you have no control over, this is virtually impossible.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation guys. I learned here.

Comment: @Johnny If it is some specific function that you can decompose into several steps _(probably a loop)_ then, modify the function to be checking for the timeout _(as Mateusz suggested)_. If it would be any generic function, then I would just recommend you to learn about effect systems, then check the fourth options I mentioned earlier and pick one.

Comment: And if you guys want to compose an answer, I would be happy to accept it. I think it could be helpful to other as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's not possible in JVM without applying some effect system like `cats-effect`, `fs2`, `monix` or `Zio`.

We need to have another thread to trigger the time timeout. Another issue, is when you calling with `runWithTimeout(Thread.sleep(1 hours))`, it will release the caller thread but it will eat the thread from the thread pool for 1 hour.

Still, to go this way, you can do something like:

```
object Execution {

  def runWithTimeout[T](timeout: Duration)(f: => T)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Option[T] = {
    try {
      Some(Await.result(Future(f), timeout))
    } catch {
      case e: TimeoutException => None
    }
  }
}
```